# Android Add AsyncTask to PreferenceActivity to load a lot of preferences the first time

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog, preferenceactivity

I have an application with quite a lot of preferences. So when the user loads the Preferences the first time, it takes quite a while. So the UI is freezing while loading the prefs.

This is why I want to add a dialog telling the user that the prefs are loading.

The problem is, that loading the preferences is only allowed on the UI thread because when I am trying to load my preferences in the Async Task, I get this:

> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4830): Caused by:
>   android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

So when I add runOnUiThread() to the Async Task the whole purpose of doing it in the AsyncTask gets destroyed:

```
public class ApplicationPreferences extends PreferenceActivity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    new ProgressTask(ApplicationPreferences.this).execute();
}

private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private Context context;

    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public ProgressTask(ListActivity activity) {
        context = activity;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                initPreferences();

            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

}

/*
* THIS TAKES LONG THE FIRST TIME
*/
private void initPreferences() {


    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    // preferences
    ListPreference pref1 = (ListPreference) findPreference(getString(R.string.pref1));

    // ........ etc


}




public static void start(Context context) {
    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ApplicationPreferences.class));
}  }
```

How can I do this better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the best solution that I could think of:

If you have a very big preference file you have to call

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(context, R.xml.mypreferencefile, false);
```

at some point on the UI thread.

I do this at the end of a initializing phase of the app. In that way the user is the least confused about some short freezing of the app.

This command initializes the file the first time with the default values. After that the file is available and can be accessed fairly quickly.

Answer (score 0):

> So when I add runOnUiThread() to the Async Task the whole purpose of
>   doing it in the AsyncTask gets destroyed.

I am not quite sure I understand that, but if you want to show progress dialog to the user then isn't it expected that the user will wait for the task to finish?

On the other hand if you want to load the preferences in real background task use ordinary java Thread - it is true that non-UI threads can't create AsyncTasks.

**Edit**: After the comment you added probably this will help you (changing part of your code in ApplicationPreferences#onCreate):

```
ProgressTask pTask = new ProgressTask(ApplicationPreferences.this);
pTask.execute();
// Wait for the async task to finish the specified amount of time.
pTask.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // Choose appropriate timeframe
```

That way the main thread will halt and hopefully the weird behavior will be handled. 
Once again: feel free to comment if I do not solve your issue yet.

Comment: No it is expected to wait. But so far the dialog will not appear until shortly before the whole task is already finished. So its Menu->Settings and then freeze and then dialog and then quickly after that the prefs are shown